# Hololens project Azure consumption

Tags: azure, hololens

Working on a project for our client, an aftermarket car parts retailer together with our partner who are doing lots of cool stuff with AR and VR. The idea is to use Hololens and to try to help our client with logistic operations in their big warehouse. Scenarios like freeing warehouse worker hands (pick by sight option), to show navigation through Hololens, scan barcodes and etc. Anyway, trying to get some founding from local Microsoft office, but unfortunately only way to get some founding is if there will be some serious Azure consumption. I'm not a tech person in this project and seems very difficult at the moment to figure out what could be potential Azure consumption for a project like this. I mean, most of the work that was done so far was concerning indoor location how to locate a person in a warehouse. Any thoughts on our problem?
Thanks in advance,
Marko

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the question is "What Azure Services are suited to my product?" So that's the answer I'll answer.

At the time of this answer, a few Azure Mixed Reality specific services have been announced by Microsoft:

[Azure Spatial Anchors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/spatial-anchors/)

[Azure Remote Rendering](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/remote-rendering/)

[Azure Digital Twins](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/digital-twins/)

From what you've said about your product, I would think Spatial Anchors and Digital Twins especially could be useful. They could assist with navigation by storing and sharing a digital version of the warehouse between multiple devices.